# Generics and Lists

Tags: c#, templates

I have 3 classes, 1 class is a parent class (**Account**) and the other two are child classes (**Cheque** and **Savings**). How do I create a method in a GenericList Class to display all information from a parent class (i.e. FullName, AccountNumber) instead of using two different list collection classes?

This is what I have so far...

```
public class GenericListOperations<T>
{
    // This is the code to reverse the list but it doesnt work
    public List<T> Generic_Reverse_list(List<T> e)
    {
        List<T> b = new List<T>();
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a LINQ operation `.Reverse()` already.  But your method needs to declare the type parameter - `public List<T> Generic_Reverse_List<T>(List<T> e)` to be valid syntax

Comment: I'm not sure what `Generic_Reverse_list` has to do with "display all information from a parent class", or where "to reverse the list" came from (the text above doesn't mention that) - can you clarify? Although I suspect an obvious answer might be: "just call `ToString()`; override `ToString()` as appropriate in the child classes"

Comment: @Jonesopolis there is no need for the method to declare `T`; the type (`GenericListOperations<T>`) already does that. Making it a generic method with `T` would make for a completely different and unrelated `T`

Comment: @MarcGravell whoops yep didnt look at the class definition

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question, you want an explicit way of returning a List of Accounts whether Account be a Cheque or Savings. If that is correct, you can just contrain the Type T to

```
where T : Account
```

or specifically

```
public class GenericListOperations<T> where T : Account
```

This is for your reference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Not only that but you can also just return a List of Account instead of a generic

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I *believe* you're trying to get at the common properties of the Cheque and Savings class that they've inherited from the Account class.

In this case you can achieve that by modifying your class definition to:

```
public class GenericListOperations<T> where T : Account
```

You can also apply that to functions individually if you wish.